# Getting anonymousUser even logged in under spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm new to spring security. Below configuration had been done under my app:

```
 http
  .sessionManagement()
  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
  .and()
  .exceptionHandling()
  .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthenticatedEntryPoint())
  .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), protectedUrls)
  .and()
  .addFilterBefore(bearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers(permittedUrls).permitAll()
  .requestMatchers(protectedUrls)
  .authenticated()
  .and()
  .csrf().disable()
  .formLogin().disable()
  .httpBasic().disable();
```

I'm fetching logged in user's name using the below code:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
return user.getUsername();
```

But `authentication.getPrincipal()` is returning `anonymousUser` instead of loggedInUser!

Can someone please help what is the reason behind it and how to fix this!

Comment: Can you show your bearerTokenAuthenticationFilter ?

Comment: If that is the anonymous user, your authentication filter doesn't integrate properly with Spring Security and the user never gets set.